# Angular2 How to switch baseURL between prodmode and test mode

Tags: angular, production

Hi I am currently testing my app in development mode and i have baseURL globally set but now I want to enable production mode and I want to use a different baseURL in production mode and switch two baseURLs between two mode (dev mode and prod mode)

How can I do this?

I am using npm run dev-start command to run dev mode.

Comment: Angular CLI projects have environments to support exactly that use-case. Use the CLI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's too easy with angular cli. Firstly, go to your `.angular-cli.json` file and edit `environments`;

```
"environments": {
     "dev": "environment/environment.ts",
     "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
     "yourCustomEnv": "environments/environment.yourCustomEnv.ts"
}
```

Secondly, add api url as a property in `environment.yourCustomEnv.ts` file;

```
export const environment = {
     production: ...,
     apiUrl: 'youApiUrl'
}
```

Afterwards, use `environment` variable wherever you want to set the api url;

```
import { environment } from 'pathTo/environments/environment';
export class XService {
     apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
     ...
}
```

Finally, build your application with the following commands;

```
ng build --env=yourCustomEnv ...
```

Angular-cli automatically use `environment.yourCustomEnv.ts` file at every place where you import `environment`.

By the way, be sure that your all `environment` variables have same properties.