# How to programmatically know if I am building with -prod flag (ng build -prod)

Tags: docker, build, webpack

I am using docker so, in production mode I am using linked containers with URLs like "http://api:3000/"
instead of "http://localhost:3000/" while in dev mode.

I would like to be able to use "http://api:3000/" if "ng build -prod" and stay with "localhost" while developing.

How can I do my if( "-prod" ) ?

Thanks for reading me, I hope my question is clear.

EDIT: Everything was explain in a commentary in environment.ts
[image]

Comment: If you just want to change variables between development mode and production mode, take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136109/angular2-how-to-switch-baseurl-between-prodmode-and-test-mode/43157274#43157274).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have environments/environment.ts, and there is a json

```
export const environment = {
    production = false
};
```

And you can access it within your application with importing it and then using it with if(environment.production)

or use the built in angular module like in 
[How to check if Angular 2 app is running in production or dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535386/how-to-check-if-angular-2-app-is-running-in-production-or-dev)

Comment: Thanks, I knew that I had this code in my environment.ts but I didn't know if it is linked or not with "ng build -prod"

OK, I just found a nice commentary in environment.ts that explain everything, Thanks !